# Site is not accessable through public IP on AWS windows instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new on AWS console. I am trying to host my website for testing on AWS ec2 windows instance. but it show the error  (taking to long too respond).

Steps i used to host the site:

```
 1. Added a custom tcp rule in AWS console with all ip and port is 8080.
 2. Host the website on IIS and bind with the IP address and port. But site is not accessed by it.

When I change the public ip to private IP so I am able to access the site only its local.
```

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, help support the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).

Comment: Could you please clarify your configuration? Is your website hosted on the standard HTTP port 80? If so, your Security Group will need to allow Inbound access on Port 80. What do you mean by "I am able to access the site" -- from what machine can you access via private IP -- is it from the same server? Anything more you can explain would be helpful!

Comment: I am able to access the site on that hosted machine via private machine like (localhost). Yes that is the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up an IIS server on 8080 on Server 2012 in the last month, so I can run through thisfrom memory.  Assuming you can get the server runner properly on 8080, there's only a few things to do:

1. make sure the public IP is routed right on the VPC, I think in the default VPC that's a given.
2. check the security groups and make sure one's open to *your* public IP on the apporopriate port.
3. open the firewall on the server.  This did it for me: `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName http-8080 -Action Allow -Direction Inbound -Description "Allow port 8080 inbound for http" -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 8080`

And it should work!

https://gist.github.com/farrellit/9b0de7d0e77f144c6786fce71badc341 is a summary of the commands needed to verify 1 and 2 at the command line.